# SES domain verification for non existent domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses, amazon-simple-email-service

I have setup SES in sandbox account to test sending emails. I created domain identity for sending emails. I used a (sub)domain (say, test.example.com) which does not exist; whereas example.com does exist. I have added CNAME records in my DNS and the domain identity is verified.

(reference https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/troubleshoot-verification.html)

- `nslookup -type=NS test.example.com` outputs that **server cannot find test.example.com: NXDOMAIN**
- where `nslookup -type=CNAME ...` does return expected output.

I do not understand the following: How is my domain identity marked as verified when server cannot find the domain test.example.com?